# Disposing Label only removes Text WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, controls

So I create labels runtime, but for some reason when I Dispose them:

```
Content.Dispose();
Header.Dispose();
```

the Background color still stays also all events I hooked up to it. Also when maually removing them from the Controls they still stay:

[image]

What I tried besides that was alling the Update method on the form, but nothing changes besides a short kind of a "blink". This is driving me crazy for hours now.

Comment: Reproduce this in a small program in less than 30 lines.  In other words, create a proper [mcve]. Right now it's not answerable.

Comment: It is already answerd thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the labels from the `Controls` collection of the form.

```
Content.SomeEvent -= Content_SomeEvent; // Unhook event handlers.
Controls.Remove(Content);
Content.Dispose();

Controls.Remove(Header);
Header.Dispose();
```

---

Apparently (according to a comment) the problem was that the labels were created twice.

Comment: Also I am having all of the logic in a different class and I get the Controls collection  in the constructor of the class.

Comment: I also unsubscribed from all events, didn't help either.

Comment: Even making them invisible doesn't help.

Comment: I just made a test. It works for me (only Remove and Dispose). Are you sure that the background color is from the lables? Or is it the color of some container control? Is the label directly on the form or is it contained in another control (like TabControl, Panel etc)?

Comment: Okay it seems that for some reason the lables get created twice, I will mark yours as the answer, thanks for your help :)